# calculating distance from one point to another

Tags: c++, math

So i have my double that calculates the distance

```
    double calculate2DDistance(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{
    return sqrt((x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2);
}
```

Note i'm calling this method from a header called math.h into my main

My testing line in main.h

```
cout << calculate2DDistance(2.0, 4.0, 3.0, 1.0) << endl;
```

and it either prints out the completely wrong answer or -1.#IND

Whats going on ?

Comment: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B).

Comment: Do you actually want `int x1, int y1 ... ` or `double x1, double y1 ... `?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++, the `^` operator means bitwise-XOR.

To elevate a number to a power, use [`std::pow`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow):

```
return sqrt(std::pow(x2 - x1, 2) + std::pow(y2 - y1, 2));
```

Or, in your very case (mere squaring), it would be more efficient to just use multiplications:

```
const int dx = x2 - x1;
const int dy = y2 - y1;
return sqrt((dx * dx) + (dy * dy));
```

Comment: Brilliant thank you i didnt know that the ^was a bitwise operator

Comment: Even if the values are not integers, the `dx = x2 - x1;` and `dx * dx` is probably quicker than calling the generic `pow` function.

Comment: @Mats yeah I edited out the "integer" part in the meantime. ;)